# remember-me sessions spring security rest int GRAILS

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, session-timeout, remember-me

I'm new to using Grails, and I need to create long sessions, in a rest API, but I can't find any information on how to do this, I would really appreciate your help
currently my system is using grails 2.5, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:1.5.4 and
spring-security-core:2.0-RC4',
my system has logins by email and password connected to a website that uses the core and I am creating the API part, to connect from a mobile application, the main objective is that for these applications I can have the option to maintain the section started like social networks like Facebook or Gmail, on the other hand for the web memcache is used to assign the life time of the sessions, which I am not sure how to use for the mobile part, I have been trying to create the InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent, AuthenticationSuccessEvent, HttpSessionListener listeners, but I'm not sure how this area works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

the laravel/lumen framework has a system variable that you can configure in the config/jwt.php file that has the following syntax 'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60), here you can modify the 60 and change it to the time you require, you can search for something similar for your plugin